# Ayuda para ejecutar accion desde un nuevo escenario en javafx

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Agregue una nueva escena despues de pasar el login. ahora no me funciona alguna accion que ejecutos desde un boton en la nueva escena. Esta es la clase principal.

```
            package controllers;

            import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
            import java.io.IOException;

            import com.sun.glass.ui.Window.Level;

            import controllers.index.IndexController;
            import controllers.login.LoginController;
            import javafx.application.Application;
            import javafx.stage.Screen;
            import javafx.stage.Stage;
            import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
            import javafx.scene.Parent;
            import javafx.scene.Scene;
            import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
            import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
            import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
            import javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory;

            public class Main extends Application {
                private Stage stage;
                private BorderPane rootLayout;
                javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

                @Override
                public void start(Stage stage) {
                    this.stage = stage;
                    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);//SE BLOQUEAN LAS OPCIONES DE VENTANAS minimizar,maximizar,cerrar.
                    stage.setTitle("Sistema Idiomas RUGE");
                    initRootLayout();//se inicializa el layout principal rootLayout
                    showLoginView();//se muestra la vista del login
                } 

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    launch(args);
                }
                /**
                 * Funcion para inicializar el archivo RootLayout el cual sera el layout padre de todos los escenarios.
                 */
                public void initRootLayout() {
                    try {
                        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("rootLayout/RootLayout.fxml"));
                        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
                        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
                        stage.setScene(scene);
                        stage.show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                /**
                 * Funcion para mostrar la vista login.
                 */
                public void showLoginView() {
                    try {

                        // Load person overview.
                        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("login/login.fxml"));
                        AnchorPane loginView = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
                        rootLayout.setCenter(loginView);
                        LoginController controller = loader.getController();
                        controller.setMainApp(this);
                        setViewCenter();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                /**
                 * Funcion para ingresar al sistema.
                 * Esta funcion se usa en LoginController en caso de que los datos del usuario hayan sido correctos.
                 */
                public void gotoProfile() {
                    try {
                        replaceSceneContent("index/index.fxml");

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("error al iniciar"+ex);
                    }
                }
                /**
                 * Funcion para remplazar un escenario por otro.
                 * Se enviara de parametro la ruta del archivo fxml que se mostrara.
                 */ 
                private AnchorPane replaceSceneContent(String fxml) throws Exception {
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxml));
                    AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
                    Scene scene = stage.getScene();
                    scene = new Scene(page,1000,600);
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.sizeToScene();
                    stage.show();
                    setViewCenter();
                    IndexController controller = loader.getController();
                    controller.setMainApp(this);
                    return page;
                }
                /**
                 * Funcion para setear la ventana en el centro de la pantalla
                 */
                private void setViewCenter(){
                    stage.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - stage.getWidth()) / 2); 
                    stage.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - stage.getHeight()) / 2); 
                }

            }
```

La cual cuando ingresa desde el login ejecuta la funcion gotoProfile() la que remplazara la escena por la nueva donde esta el fxml index.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

            <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
            <?import com.jfoenix.controls.*?>
            <?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
            <?import javafx.geometry.*?>
            <?import java.lang.*?>
            <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
            <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

            <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" maxHeight="600.0" maxWidth="10000.0" minHeight="600.0" minWidth="1000.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1000.0" scaleZ="0.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFF;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.index.IndexController">
               <rotationAxis>
                  <Point3D />
               </rotationAxis>
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow />
               </effect>
               <children>
                  <JFXHamburger fx:id="hamburger" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="12.0" />
                  <JFXDrawer fx:id="drawer" prefHeight="598.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="1.0" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#prueba" text="Button" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="300.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="300.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
```

Es aqui cuando intento ejecutar el metodo prueba desde el boton que esta en index.fxml y no me funciona. Aunque probe poner la funcion prueba en initialize de indexController y si funciona.

```
            package controllers.index;
            import java.net.URL;
            import java.util.ResourceBundle;

            import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDrawer;
            import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXHamburger;
            import com.jfoenix.transitions.hamburger.HamburgerBackArrowBasicTransition;

            import controllers.Main;
            import javafx.fxml.FXML;
            import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
            import javafx.scene.control.Button;
            import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
            import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

            public class IndexController implements Initializable{
                private Main main;
                @FXML
                private AnchorPane anchorPane;

                @FXML
                private Button button;

                public void setMainApp(Main main) {
                    this.main = main;
                }


                @Override
                public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

                }

                @FXML
                public void prueba(){
                    System.out.println("Sirve");
                }

            }
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor considera hacer el [tour] y revisar [ask].

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT

He cambiado el método de privado a público, como estaba en tu código:

Tu botón necesita un [`ActionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/convenience_methods.htm):

```
    @FXML
 public void prueba(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Sirve");
 }
```

Comment: Perdon se me olvido ponerl el ActionEvent. Pero aun asi sigue sin ejecutar el metodo prueba.

Comment: ¿Da algún error o simplemente no funciona?

Comment: No funciona no da ningun error.

Comment: Fíjate que por ahora lo único que haces es imprimir en la consola la frase `Sirve`... ¿Has mirado en la consola si se imprime algo cuando pulsas tu botón.? Imagino que te aparece en tu pantalla y es clickable.

Comment: Exactamente es lo que no entiendo. Al dar click no pasa nada en la consola.